# iOS 11 - Cannot access UIView of UIBarButton

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to create a badge number on the top right corner of my UIBarButton. For iOS 9 and 10 it works fine but with iOS 11 I cannot access the view of the button which I normally do like this:

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
    func createBadge() {
         guard let view = self.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else {
             return
         }
    }
}
```

I understand that using key values is not a good idea for cases like this, as the key can change. But is there an alternative here, using public APIs so that the solution works for iOS 11 too?
Thanks.

Comment: If you know that attempting to access the private subview structure is a bad idea, then why are you trying to find a workaround to the bad idea? Why not do it properly so you don't have to fix your code every time iOS changes the private implementation?

Comment: Well I agree, my question is not asking for the right key value for iOS 11, But for an alternative implementation that fits all the available iOS versions.

Comment: Your question asks for an alternative for iOS 11 so it sounds like you want the updated private key that works in iOS 11. You should update your question to make it clear that you want a proper solution using public APIs that works from iOS 9 through iOS 11 (and later).

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `UIBarButtonItem` from a custom view. Add the badge to the custom view

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use a custom view and embed it in your `UIToolbar` / `UINavigationBar` instead of a `UIBarbuttonItem`

The custom view could contain a UIButton and your badge view.

Via storyboard, simply drag and drop a UIView to the slot in your bar and add a UIButton as subview. Depending on your implementation of a badge, you could just create a UILabel and position it via constraints relative to your UIButton.

Create IBOutlets for those and set them up programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let button = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
    button.addTarget(self.target, action: self.action!, for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    button.target(forAction: self.action!, withSender: self.target)
    button.setImage(self.image, for: .normal)
    self.customView = button
    guard let view = self.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else {
        return
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.